# what guarantee `view` command to open a file as read only?

Tags: vim

`view` command do open a file in ready only mode. 
However, I found that in my mac, `view` command is actually the soft link to vim:

`ll /usr/bin/view` output:

> `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     3B Nov 19 14:25 /usr/bin/view -> vim`

So I wonder: when I open a file with this command:`/usr/bin/view /path/to/file`. how does vim automaticlly turn on read only mode as I have not set any specific param?

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/main.c#L1699

Answer (score 2):

Commands can look up the name by which they were invoked (using, for example, `argv[0]` in C) and change their behaviour accordingly. So in this case `vim` knows that if is is run as `view`, it should behave as if the read-only `-R` flag has been set.

From the `vim` man page:

```
   Vim behaves differently, depending on the name of the command (the exe‐
   cutable may still be the same file).

   vim       The "normal" way, everything is default.

   view      Start in read-only mode.  You will be protected from  writing
             the files.  Can also be done with the "-R" argument.
```